# how to wait for sendBroadcast to finish

Tags: java, android

I am doing a media  file scan using sendBroadcast. Then I need to wait till it's complete after doing sendBroadcast. How do I do this in Android ?

I know I can use a simple while logic here but I am looking for a better approach

```
context.sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED, Uri.parse("file://" + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory())));

// wait here till till do something completed
```

Receiver

```
private BroadcastReceiver mediaScanner = new BroadcastReceiver(){

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String action = intent.getAction();
                if (action.equals(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_FINISHED)) {
                  // Do some thing here. 
                }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code to check whether media scanner is running.

```
public static final boolean isMediaScannerScanning(final ContentResolver cr) {
    boolean result = false;
    final Cursor cursor = query(cr, MediaStore.getMediaScannerUri(), new String[] { MediaStore.MEDIA_SCANNER_VOLUME }, null,
            null, null);
    if (cursor != null) {
        if (cursor.getCount() == 1) {
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            result = "external".equals(cursor.getString(0));
        }
        cursor.close();
    }
    return result;
}
```

I posted the answer here
http://androidbridge.blogspot.com/2012/06/how-to-check-whether-android-media.html

Comment: And why don't you post the answer **here**?!

Answer (score 0):

You can look for the [Observable pattern](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Design-Pattern/AsimpledemoofObservableandObserver.htm) in Java, it matchs your will